# Divide by zero error encountered - using numeric value and DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate this....

```
 CONVERT(varchar(9), CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,3),tblBatchActivity.StopQty / 
    DATEDIFF( HOUR, tblBatchStatus.Date , tblBatchActivity.LastEdited))) AS Rate
```

tblBatchActivity.StopQty is numeric value

tblBatchStatus.Date , tblBatchActivity.LastEdited are date and time value

---

Here is my Full Query

```
SELECT        
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), tblBatch.FinalizedDate, 126) AS FinalizedDate, 
    tblFinishProduct.FinishProdutDescription, 
    tblBatchActivity.EndProductCode, 
    tblBatch.BatchID, 
    tblPckingType.PackingTitle, 
    tblBatchActivity.StopQty, 
    CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEDIFF(second, tblBatchStatus.Date, tblBatchActivity.LastEdited)/3600)
        + ':'
        + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEDIFF(second, tblBatchStatus.Date, tblBatchActivity.LastEdited) % 3600) / 60), 2)
        + ':'
        + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(second, tblBatchStatus.Date, tblBatchActivity.LastEdited) % 60), 2) AS 'TimeTaken (HH:MM:SS)',
    Section.SectionName,
    CONVERT(varchar(9), CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,3),tblBatchActivity.StopQty / NULLIF(DATEDIFF(HOUR, tblBatchStatus.Date, tblBatchActivity.LastEdited), 0))) AS Rate
FROM tblSection INNER JOIN
    tblProductManufacturing ON tblSection.SectionID = tblProductManufacturing.SectionID INNER JOIN
    tblSTDBatch INNER JOIN
    tblBatch ON tblSTDBatch.STDBatchID = tblBatch.BatchSTDBatchID INNER JOIN
    tblBatchActivity ON tblBatch.BatchID = tblBatchActivity.BatchID ON tblProductManufacturing.ProductCode = tblSTDBatch.STDBasicProductCode INNER JOIN
    tblFinishProduct ON tblBatchActivity.EndProductCode = tblFinishProduct.FinishProductCode INNER JOIN
    tblPckingType ON tblFinishProduct.FinishProdutPackingTypeID = tblPckingType.PackingID INNER JOIN
    tblBatchStatus ON tblBatch.BatchID = tblBatchStatus.BatchID
WHERE (CONVERT(date, tblBatch.FinalizedDate) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31') AND 
    (tblBatch.BatchType = 'Basic') AND 
    (tblBatchActivity.ActType <> 'Manufacturing') AND 
    (tblBatchStatus.Status = 8) AND 
    (tblProductManufacturing.Type = 'Pack')
ORDER BY tblBatch.BatchI
```

D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NULLIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to ignore `0` :

```
NULLIF(DATEDIFF(HOUR, tblBatchStatus.Date, tblBatchActivity.LastEdited), 0)
```

By using `NULLIF()` result will be `null`, to ignore `null` value you can use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: but then result will be NULL, as value/null = null

Comment: @PawelCzapski. . .  Yes result will be `null`. To ignore `null` then use `COALESCE(<>, <value>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here

```
DATEDIFF( HOUR, tblBatchStatus.Date , tblBatchActivity.LastEdited)
```

result of this is 0, so tblBatchStatus.Date hour is the same as tblBatchActivity.LastEdited

EDIT

you can use CASE statement
as below

```
select case when DATEDIFF( HOUR, getdate() , getdate()) <> 0 
    then CONVERT(varchar(9), CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,3), 50) 
        / DATEDIFF( HOUR, getdate() , getdate())) 
    else CONVERT(varchar(9), CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,3), 50)) -- or different logic
    end AS Rate
```

Comment: @K.Badra, you were right, edited to use case statement